# Command to exit script but not the SSH session

Tags: linux, ssh, bash

This is my first post here and I am not an expert of Linux /Bash scripting yet. :-)

So I wrote the following code for my Raspberry Pi and it works fine except for one small issue.

I am using SSH to log into the raspberry Pi.When pin 17 is high, ( digital logic value of 1 aka 5 volts ), I want the message “I noticed a 1” printed on the terminal output and then I want to exit the script and still stay logged into the raspberry Pi.

The problem that I am facing is when the script sees a logic value of 1, it shuts down the entire ssh connection adn takes me back to my laptop's terminal session.

I dont want the script to exit the ssh connection when pin 17 reads a 1. I just want it to stop executing the scriot and take me back to the raspberry Pi terminal where I am still logged into the raspberry Pi so that I can do other stuff.

I basically DO NOT want to close the SSH session when the scipt exits.
Could you please give me some suggestions to fix this issue?

Thank you for the reply!

```sh
pin=17
gpio mode $pin in
while true; do
    if [[ $(gpio read $pin) -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "I noticed a 1 whcih means I noticed 5 volts!"
        return
    elif [[ $(gpio read $pin) -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Did not see a 1, so I will keep looping"
        echo ""
        sleep 2
    fi
done
```

Comment: How exactly did you run this script?

Comment: I just typed in ./logicreadscript.sh in the Raspberry Pi's terminal. Then waited a few seconds and gave 0 volts to pin 12. It printed "Did not see a 1, so I will keep looping" Later, I gave pin 12 , 5 volts, and it printed ""I noticed a 1 whcih means I noticed 5 volts!" and then abruptly exited the SSH session.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be on topic here. You may be able to get help at our sister sites [raspberrypi.se] or [unix.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Server Fault. Try using the following code:

```sh
pin=17
gpio mode $pin in
while true; do
    if [[ $(gpio read $pin) -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "I noticed a 1 whcih means I noticed 5 volts!"
        kill -INT $$
    elif [[ $(gpio read $pin) -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Did not see a 1, so I will keep looping"
        echo ""
        sleep 2
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I was busy editing mypost when you sent me the message. Any ways, having 'return' did not help. The script  gives the following error and keeps running.        ./logicreadscript.sh: line 6: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script

Comment: Well my original script doesnt throw an error. It just displays "I notices a 1 whcih means I notices 5 volts!" and then says "connection closed" to rasp@192.168.168.1

Comment: I updated, please try it (I haven't the time to test it sadly).

Comment: Your last code worked. thank you very much for your time! Have a nice day! I am sorry about the accepting edit issue before. This is my first time here and the website seems to work a little different from a regular forum. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, we're here to learn. If you want to improve your questions, please have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask). As you said, my answer helped you. Please consider marking as answer (the green check on my post) :) have a nice day too

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you do something like

```sh
ssh raspberrypi /path/to/script
```

So, yes, when the script exits, the ssh session ends too.

However, in the script, instead of exiting, spawn an interactive shell:

```sh
    if [[ $(gpio read $pin) -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "I noticed a 1 whcih means I noticed 5 volts!"
        exec bash -li
```

That *replaces* the running script process with an interactive login shell.

You *might* need `ssh -t` or `ssh -tt`, test without first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you saying that I might need to do ssh -t raspberrypi /path/to/script or ssh -tt raspberrypi /path/to/script ?

Comment: You might need one or the other. But maybe not.